# let the girth of G is at least 2k. Prove that the diameter of Gis at least k.

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory

The question is to prove that if graph G has at least one cycle and that the girth of G (Girth= length of shortest cycle) is at least 2k, then the diameter of G is at least k.

*My attempt:*

I tried to show both cases if we have even cycle and odd cycle. Let C be the cycle with girth at least 2k. If C is even, then maximum distance between 2 random vertices on C is (2K/2). If C is odd, then the maximum distance between two random vertices on C is at least (2k/2)+1.

Therefore, proved. Any suggestion or modification?

Comment: How? Which points should I try to mention?

Comment: Seems to be on the right track but lacking some detail.


"If C is even, then maximum distance between 2 random vertices on C is $(2K/2)$".


This is true but what happens here that prevents 2 opposing vertices on the cycle of having a shorter path between them outside the cycle?

Comment: Hmm, I can add that the shortest cycle(Girth) on a graph is an induced subgraph of G. Therefore, there can't be any edge uv, where uv not element in C, joining the two random vertices on C

Comment: Anything else I should add?

Comment: That should be enough. Alternatively, you can state directly the proof of why the shortest cycle is an induced subgraph which is short anyway

Comment: To prove that the shortest cycle in an induced subgraph: (By contradiction)? That assume cycle C is shortest cycle but not induced, therefore there should be at least 1 edge between 2 vertices x and y where the edge belongs to G but not to C. This edge is a chord and hence we can make a shorter cycle using this chord which contradicts our assumption. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. What happens if you have you have two vertices $u, v$ whose distance is $d$ in the cycle and there is another path $P$ joining $u$ and $v$ with distance less than $k-d$ and such that no vertices of $P$ are on the cycle (except for $u$ and $v$)? What can you say about going from $u$ to $v$ in the cycle and then from $v$ to $u$ through $P$?

Comment: I am confused why you used k-d and not 2k-d? If we add the distance going from u to v and then from v to u, we get a cycle of length k. Can you elaborate more? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I meant $2k - d$ indeed

Comment: It is okay! But then won't having path p contradicts the fact that the cycle that contains u and v is the shortest cycle?

Comment: Exactly, that is the proof that no such path exists. Thus, if two vertices $u$ and $v$ have distance $k$ in the cycle, they must have that distance in that whole graph

Comment: Oh got it! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be a smallest-length cycle of length $m$ and let $x$ and $y$ be two points furthest from each other on $C$. So the distance between $x$ and $y$ in $C$ is $\lfloor \frac{m}{2} \rfloor$, which, as $m$ is at least $2k$, is at least $k$. So let $P_1$ be a path from $x$ to $y$ on $C$ of length $\lfloor \frac{m}{2} \rfloor$.

Now suppose the diameter of $C$ is less than $\lfloor \frac{m}{2} \rfloor$. Then there is a path $P_2$ of length $l$ $< \lfloor \frac{m}{2} \rfloor$ from $x$ to $y$. Then the graph $P_1 \cup P_2$ [a vertex $v$ is in $P_1 \cup P_2$ iff $v$ is on either $P_1$ or $P_2$ and an edge is in $P_1 \cup P_2$ iff $e$ is in either $P_1$ or $P_2$] has no more than $(\lfloor \frac{m}{2} \rfloor +1)+l-1$ vertices [make sure you see why], and has at least one cycle. [Indeed, as $P_1$ is strictly longer than $P_2$, there is at least one vertex $x'$ in $P_1$ but not on $P_2$. So writing $P=x_1x_2\ldots x_{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}$ let $i$ and $j$ be integers $i+1<j$ such that $x_i$ and $x_j$ is in $P_2$ but $x_{i'} $ is not for $i' \in \{i+1,\ldots , j-1\}$. Next let $P'_2$ be the subpath of $P_2$ with endpoints $x_i$ and $x_j$. Then $P'2$ intersects $x_ix_{i+1}\ldots x_j$ at precisely $x_i$ and $x_j$, and so $P'_2 \cup x_ix_{i+1}\ldots x_j$ is a cycle.]

This however, implies that there is a cycle of length no more than the number of vertices in $P_1 \cup P_2$ which is no more than $(\lfloor \frac{m}{2} \rfloor +1)+l-1$ $> m$, which is a contradiction.